# Using count() in soql in apex Trigger.new

Tags: apex

```
List<CustObjChild__c> cItems = [SELECT COUNT() FROM CustObjChild__c 
             WHERE MyParentId__c IN :Trigger.new];
```

Getting the error:  Illegal assignment from Integer to List. In Salesforce Apex Trigger.

Trigger is in the child object which has a Master-Detail relationship.

Any pointers? Thanks!

---

I had tried with Integer earlier and tried again now with Integer, but when executing the trigger, keeps getting the error:

Line: 19, Column: 1
System.DmlException: Insert failed.  execution of AfterInsert caused by: System.QueryException: Invalid bind expression type of CustObjChild__c does not match domain of foreign key Class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the children per parent, you want to group by the parent ID, and use COUNT(ID) instead of COUNT(). Also, the return type will then be an AggregateResult, not a "child object."

```
Map<Id, AggregateResult> counts = new Map<Id, AggregateResult>([
  SELECT MyParentId__c Id, COUNT(ID) sum
  FROM CustObjChild__c
  WHERE MyParentId__c = :Trigger.new
  GROUP BY MyParentId__c
]);
```

You can then get the values for each record:

```
for(MyParent__c record: Trigger.new) {
  Integer childRecordCount = (Integer)counts.get(record.Id)?.get('sum');
  if(childRecordCount == null) {
    childRecordCount = 0;
  }
  // ...
}
```

Comment: I am not sure if this is what I want. Because all I am trying to do is get the total number of child records related to its parent record and if this total number is equal to a count field in the parent object, only then execute the method in the child after insert trigger.

Comment: @STSF Yep, you need the count per parent, because otherwise bulk loads won't behave the way you think it should. You can read more about [bulkification](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/v/modules/apex_triggers/apex_triggers_bulk).

Comment: Right. For bulkification. I am gonna try this now. Thanks.

Comment: @STSF I presumed you had this code directly in a trigger, not a handler. You'll probably want to pass in the Trigger.new context variable and use that in your handler code, or cast it to the correct object list, as in `for(MyParent__c record: (MyParent__c[])Trigger.new)`

Comment: Yes, I am using the Kevin O Hara's trigger framework. That fixed the deploy error: Invalid loop variable type expected SObject... but now getting the error: System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY, : execution of AfterInsert caused by: System.QueryException: Invalid bind expression type of CustObjChild__c does not match domain of foreign key Class....

Comment: @STSF The IDs you're trying to query don't match the type of the field in question. You'll need to make sure you're querying the right obect.

Answer (score 0):

`COUNT` in SOQL return Integer.

```
Integer intCount = [SELECT COUNT() FROM CustObjChild__c WHERE MyParentId__c IN :Trigger.new];
```